# Convert Data From One Type to Another ; astype/lstrip method in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the '$' symbol in the 'salary' column. But its not working. What am I doing wrong? Ive tried many ways as seen below, but none of them are working. My dataframe is called "json".

```
json['salary'] = json['salary'].str.lstrip('$').astype(float)
minimal_salary = json['salary'] = json['salary'].str.replace('$','')
minimal_salary = json['salary'] = json['salary'].str.lstrip('$').astype('float')
json['minimal_salary'] = json['salary'].str.replace('$', '').str[:3].str.replace('K', '').str.strip().astype('float')
json['maximal_salary'] = json['salary'].str[6:10].str.replace('K','').str.lstrip('$').str.strip().astype('float')
json['average_salary'] = (json['minimal_salary'] + json['maximal_salary']) / 2
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you sure that json refers to the dataframe? What do you see if you run `type(json)`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work and returns the resulting DataFrame directly.

```
json.assign(Salary=lambda d: d["Salary"].replace("$", "").astype("float"))
```

Alternatively, you can do it the "regular" way.

```
json["Salary"] = json["Salary"].replace("$", "").astype("float")
```